Using MUI Modal when clicking on MUI x data grid rendered button
I was wondering how can i set a modal when u click on mui x data grid table .
i dont know how it works . and how should i put a modal inside data grid table ( throw clicking a button )

function UserDataGrid() {
  const { allUsers, filteredUsers, setFilteredUsers, traffics } =
    useContext(UserContext);

  const handleEvent = (e) => {
    console.log(e.field);
  };

  const columns = [
    { field: "id", headerName: "ای دی" },
    { field: "username", headerName: "یوزر" },
    {
      field: "enable",
      headerName: "وضعیت",
      type: "boolean",
      width: 140,
      editable: true,
      renderCell: (params) => {
        return params.value ? <p>فعال</p> : <p>غیر فعال</p>;
      },
    },
    { field: "startdate", headerName: "تاریخ شروع", headerAlign: "center" },
    { field: "finishdate", headerName: "تاریخ پایان" },
    { field: "mobile", headerName: "موبایل" },
    { field: "referral", headerName: "معرف" },
    { field: "traffic", headerName: "ترافیک" },
    {
      field: "action",
      headerName: "Action",
      width: 180,
      sortable: false,
      disableClickEventBubbling: true,

      renderCell: (params) => {
        const onClick = (e) => {
          const currentRow = params.row;
          return alert(JSON.stringify(currentRow, null, 4));
        };

        return (
          <div direction="row" spacing={2}>
            <Button onClick={onClick}>Delete</Button>
            <Button onClick={onClick}>Edit</Button>
          </div>
        );
      },
    },
  ];

  return (
    <div>
      <DataGrid
        rows={allUsers}
        columns={columns}
        loading={!allUsers.length}
        onCellClick={handleEvent}
      />
    </div>
  );
}

export default UserDataGrid;


for example i want this modal to be rendered when i click delete Button on every row with that row's detail . i want to add some buttons on row which open's a modal on click and send requests to the server .

export default function DeleteModal() {
  const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false);
  const handleOpen = () => setOpen(true);
  const handleClose = () => setOpen(false);

  return (
    <div>
      <Button onClick={handleOpen}>Open modal</Button>
      <Modal
        open={open}
        onClose={handleClose}
        aria-labelledby="modal-modal-title"
        aria-describedby="modal-modal-description"
      >
        <Box sx={style}>
          <Typography id="modal-modal-title" variant="h6" component="h2">
            Text in a modal
          </Typography>
          <Typography id="modal-modal-description" sx={{ mt: 2 }}>
            Duis mollis, est non commodo luctus, nisi erat porttitor ligula.
          </Typography>
        </Box>
      </Modal>
    </div>
  );
}



You can add the Modal component below the DataGrid Component and manage the open and close states of the Modal on Delete button click. I have implemented a solution here.

thanks alot . could u explain a bit cuz i have alot of buttons like delete to add

Each button can have its own click event and the row data can be available in each event using params available in render cell

i mean i should set State for every single one of the buttons or there is a way to manage them without setting too many states for open and close  . there is like 8 button per row

You can have 1 state with the name or id of the button as to which button is being used
